# Trouble with Parameter extensions in the Registry | %~n1

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd, registry

Trying to add a Registry entry to make symbolic links of folders I want to sync into my dropbox folder, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting one of my variables, `%~n1`, to expand.

In a batch file/command line `%~n1` would expand to the filename or last folder if no file is given, but it refuses to expand. I have tried double `%`'s in front, escaping the tilda `\~`, single and double `%`'s at the end and all combinations of those.

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

```
Echo mklink /d "%HomeDrive%%HomePath%\Dropbox\%~n1" "%1"
```

This line works when you drop a folder ont the batchfile.

My .reg file/"code":

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Sync with Dropbox"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /k mklink /d \"%%HomeDrive%%%%HomePath%%\\Dropbox\\%~n1\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: have you tried to make this with `regedit` ?

Comment: I have added this string to the registry directly: `cmd.exe /k echo %~n1 %~n1% %%~n1 %%~n1% %%~n1%% %n1 %n1% %%n1 %%n1% %%n1%% %~1 %~1% %%~1 %%~1% %%~1%% %~n %~n% %%~n %%~n% %%~n%%` and none of them expanded to the folder name.

Comment: I's impossible to read true code in the comment box, but you can edit your question.

Comment: what  data type do you give the key?

Comment: I don't specify one, but it's listed as "REG_SZ". Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: And does `Echo mklink /d "%HomeDrive%%HomePath%\Dropbox\%1" "%1"` work?

Comment: Yes, but it will give me the full path of the folder added to the end: `mklink /d "C:\Users\Jeff\Dropbox\C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\test" "C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\test"` I have just tried echoing %A to %Z, and found that %W expands to the folder ABOVE the target (`C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop`), but using the batch/commandline replace (`%variable:Find=Replace%`) doesn't work when passed through either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the string type`REG_EXPAND_SZ`.
[Registry Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: With the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` string type, only the %%'s get shown on the command line via `Echo`, but even then they're not being expanded at the command line. I also tried to escape the `~` characters in both `REG_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The %~ syntax only works for parameters: command line arguments (as you have found) or arguments passed to a subroutine, so they don't work against a simple echo statement.
The way to work around this is to just throw in a subroutine and then %~n1 will work for the first item passed to it.